# How to import multiple csv stocks files in python and do statistics on them at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

Ihave 10 csv files (stocks) which each of them have something like the following:

```
   Date        High      Low       Open      Close     Volume  Adj Close
0  2003-12-01  1.204007  1.194401  1.203398  1.196501  0.0     1.196501
1
2
.
.  
[4440 rows x 7 columns]
```

Firstly, I wonder how to import all csv files at the same time in python.

Secondly, how to some statistic analyze on them again at the same time (e.g., calculating daily return on them at the same time by the strategy buy and hold).

Comment: Read the documentation (which is excellent for Pandas). Try here first: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the list of all the csv files from the current directory

```
import os
csvs = [x  for x in listdir(os.getcwd()) if x.endswith('.csv')]
```

Hoping that you have the same set of columns for all the csvs

```
mdf = pd.DataFrame()
for csv in csvs:
    mdf = pd.concat([mdf,pd.read_csv(csv)],axis=0)
```

mdf is the master dataframe which contains all csv data

Comment: I have no idea how to run this:import os
csvs = [x  for x in listdir(os.getcwd()) if x.endswith('.csv')].Would you please show me an exact real example?

Comment: Pandas can open csv files . Each line should contain 'Date,High,Low,Open,   Close,Volume,Adj Close' header and values as each line seperated by commas eg.'2003-12-01,1.204007,1.194401,1.203398,1.19650,0.0,1.196501'